# Align vertically / horizontally using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've asked this question a few times now, but no one has been able to resolve my problem.

The problem I have is that I can't get the header to sit completely centrally within a fullpage background.

There is however one method that does work (commented out in the header tag) but faces problems when coming to full browser compatibility.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <header role="banner" id="banner" class="vcenter">
            <h1>Fix this</h1>
            <h2>Bootstrap/css</h2>
            <h3>Please</h3>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS** (rest is in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wesbbtqn/))

```
.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wesbbtqn/) to try and describe the problem I am facing. Note that the background image has been changed to a solid colour.
http://jsfiddle.net/wesbbtqn/

If someone can fix this I will be hugely grateful as it has been bugging me for ages.

EDIT - The height and width must remain flexible.

Comment: Is it possible to know/set the height of the header?

Comment: To me it's quite unclear how exactly you want it centered. Should the three lines of text be centered vertically? And should each line be centered horizontally or should all lines together be centered horizontally (making the left side of each line vertically aligned with eachother)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the height and width needs to remain flexible. And yes, all 3 lines need to be completely central in the page, both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Can't you really not use the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` trick due to browser incompatibilities? Only Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support it

Comment: Safari doesn't support it either, and as a lot of people still use safari on mac, i think that this definitely needs to be fixed.

Comment: Safari does support it, you just need to add a `-webkit-` prefix. The same for IE9 with `-ms-`. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d. There is however the problem (on every browser) that the centered content can't be larger than half the screens width or height. Lorenzo-Marcon's trick using `display: table-cell` seems like a more supported solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get correctly what you're asking:

**Horizontal centering:**

just add `text-align: center` to h1, h2 and h3.

**Vertical centering:**

One way to achieve this in pure CSS, in a supported cross-browser way, and without setting explicitly the container's height is to add `display: table` to the parent of the container, and `display: table-cell` (along with the already present `vertical-align: middle`) to the container itself (in your case: `<header>`)

```
.vcenter {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wesbbtqn/3/

Comment: I think this has sorted my problems, I'll test it on a few different browsers and report back though. Thank you

Comment: You've sorted my problem! Thanks a bunch, this problem was killing me

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/shannabarnard/wesbbtqn/4/

All I did was add

```
text-align: center;
width: 90%;
height: 50%;
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
```

to your header css.

Comment: I tried this and when on a full screen background it seems to sit underneath the background.

Comment: That sounds more like a z-index problem. Make sure your header is set to a higher z-index than the div.  If you can create your problem in a fiddle it would be easier to give you a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%; 
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Fix this</h1>
  <h2>Bootstrap/css</h2>
  <h3>Please</h3>             
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, change your css code for this class `.vcenter` to be like this:

```
.vcenter {
   display: inline;
   vertical-align: middle;
   float: none;
   text-align:center;
}
```

and then, add new class in your container element, to be like this `<div class="container-fluid text-center page-container">`.

and add new class in your css to override `height:100%;` from `.container-fluid`:

```
.page-container{
   height:auto !important;
}
```

hopefully helping .