# How to center an <h1> vertically and horizontally using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanna center an `h1` vertically and horizontally using Bootstrap. Actually I tried to use Bootstrap flexbox to align it vertically with the `align-items-center` property so in order to work it needs `height` so I give it some height but it didn't work :

[image]

The `h1` is supposed to be in place of the yellow highlights but that doesn't work.

I don't wanna use any jquery or javascript because I wanna practice bootstrap.

I don't know why but I think i should use the 2d transform property.

By the way I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984938/align-vertically-horizontally-using-bootstrap) and it didn't solve my problema.

Here is my code :

**HTML**

```
  <div class="backIMg">
<!-- Greeting -->
<div class="d-flex align-items-center  flex-column text-primary greeting-container">
  <h1 class="greeting col-sm-8 text-center m-auto display-1 font-weight-bold align-items-center align-self-center "  >Welcome</h1>

</div>

  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.backIMg .greeting-container{
height:100vh
}
```

I'm not familiar with Bootstrap. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using multiple bootstrap classes, you can use flex properties on the `.greeting-container`. You just have to add flex properties to justify and align the content in center.

```css
.backIMg .greeting-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="backIMg">
  <div class="greeting-container">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can do it like that with pure css it's easy but I wanna use bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

use:   `class="align-middle"` as described here:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/

```
<h1 class="greeting col-sm-8 text-center m-auto display-1 font-weight-bold align-items-center align-self-center align-middle"  >Welcome</h1>
```